# udevadm in Docker: The command '/bin/sh -c udevadm control --reload-rules' returned a non-zero code: 2

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I am trying to set up a Docker image, but run into the following problem when I try to run `udevadm`:

```
The command '/bin/sh -c udevadm control --reload-rules' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

Minimal reproducible Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.8-slim
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade
RUN apt-get install -y udev
RUN udevadm control --reload-rules
```

Comment: You can't dynamically add devices to a Docker container; I'm not sure it makes sense to run `udev` there.  Can you edit the question to add more details from the error message, in particular what `udevadm` prints out before it exits with an error?